# tensorflow.contrib.predictor.from_saved_model() in Tensorflow 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Currently using Tensorflow 1 and noticed tensorflow.contrib has been removed in Tensorflow 2. How to convert tensorflow.contrib.predictor.from_saved_model() to work on Tensorflow 2?

Answer (score -1):

In TF2 the Predictor API is no longer supported and is not in TF2 at all ([the whole `contrib` module is gone](https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180907-contrib-sunset.md)). You can either attempt using TF-HUB (the link above says Predictor is replaced by it), convert your model to a Keras model (the way I'd recommend if you have a custom model architecture), convert it to an `Estimator`, or stick to the latest TF1 release.